# Magento 2 Pre-Order instead of Add to Cart

Tags: magento2, module, products, product-list, addtocart

I need to be able to change the "Add to Cart" button to "Pre Order", or "Learn More", depending on a custom product attribute, release date.  Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: check this [extension](https://www.fmeextensions.com/pre-order-backorders-magento-2-extension.html) to replace Add to cart button with Pre-order.

Comment: view another extension of [magento 2 pre order](https://www.mageants.com/pre-order-extension-for-magento-2.html)

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably have to install an extension to get that feature for your magento 2 build, but unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any Pre-Order Magento 2 Extensions available for free of of magentocommerce.com

Comment: @ Tyler Voll : Is it available Pre-Order extension for Magento 1 series